# Why does using a conditional operator result in an intersection type?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a generic function that conditionally returns values based on the type of its argument, but I'm stuck trying to implement the return type.

Assuming there's a type `Basket`

```
type Basket = {
    Fruit: 'banana',
    Veggie: 'tomato'
}
```

Now if I want to conditionally return either 'banana' or 'tomato' based on the argument passed to a function, I am unable to get it to compile:

```
const f1 = <T extends keyof Basket>(t: T): T extends 'Fruit'? 'banana': 'tomato' => {
    if (t == 'Fruit') {
        return 'banana' //Error on this line - doesn't compile -- Type '"banana"' is not assignable to type '"banana" & "tomato"
    } else {
        return  'tomato' //Error on this line - doesn't compile -- Type '"tomato"' is not assignable to type '"banana" & "tomato"
    }
}
```

Now when I instantiate this after passing the right generic parameter, I get the type I expect, but it doesn't compile

```
const doesntCompile: 'banana' = f1<'Fruit'>('') //type: 'banana', which is what I want ... but this doesn't compile due to the error above.
```

However, if I don't use generics I get a sum type like so

```
//This compiles
const f2 = <T extends keyof Basket>(t: string): Basket[keyof Basket] => { //return type is 'banana' | 'tomato'
    if (t == 'yellow') {
        return  'banana'
    } else {
        return  'tomato'
    }
}
const complies: 'banana' | 'tomato' = f2<'Fruit'>('') //type: 'banana' | 'tomato', but I want the type here to be 'banana'
```

Now it compiles just fine, but I lose the benefit of type safety.

How would I get this example to work while retaining generics? Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any conditional types in your question (am I just missing them)?

Comment: Your main issue is a combination of a longstanding issue ([microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995): can't narrow `T` when you type guard on `t`) and a recent improvement to soundness ([microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769:) synthesize intersections when writing to properties via a union of keys).

Comment: @jcalz - edited for clarity. Thanks  a lot for your links. You seem to be absolutely right here, it seems to be a current limitation of the typescript compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your issue it comes from conditional types that are deferred. Look at the typescript documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types. (*search for conditional types are deferred to get to the right place in the page*).

The simplest solution is to use a separate implementation signature that is more permissive, while keeping the public signature with conditional types that is better for the caller:

```
type Basket = {
    Fruit: 'banana',
    Veggie: 'tomato'
}

function f3 <T extends keyof Basket>(t: T): Basket[T]; 
function f3 <T extends keyof Basket>(t: string): Basket[keyof Basket] {
    if (t == 'Fruit') {
        return  'banana'
    } else {
        return  'tomato'
    }
}

const complies2 = f3('Fruit'); // complies2 is "banana"
```

Note: arrow functions don't work with function overload.

Comment: Note that `Pick<Basket, T>[T]` can be replaced with just `Basket[T]`.

Comment: Also note that while the question *mentions* conditional types, the code does not seem to use them and so your explanation here about deferred conditional type resolution doesn't seem to apply.  The specific issue with intersections is due to how [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) interacts with [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995).

Comment:  for the overload solution, though!

Comment: Edited the code example in the question to use conditional types as the title implies. Looks like overloading is the way to go here.
Thank you both!